# Script executing manually but not executing through PHP.

Tags: php, python, laravel

We have one of the our python script which when executed manually works 100%  fine,but when I try to execute it through PHP it is not getting executed. Does not give any exception or error.
There is no problem with script path. Is there any way to identify this ??

Comment: @sampath Share your code here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: there's not sufficient information to make sense out of your post. please give more details, like the snippet of how are you trying to execute it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the possibilities,

1. error reporting is not enabled
2. due to change in relative paths, your script is not working

Also can you provide the full exec statement, it will be helpful for us.